# Minecraft will not launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-10

Whenever I try to launch Minecraft the launcher loads perfectly but, once I hit play, the launcher disappears for a second and then reappears with the following error message:

```
Minecraft Version: 16w40a
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 52833096 bytes (50 MB) / 151068672 bytes (144 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 16w40a
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

I have tried deleting minecraft and reinstalling, repairing minecraft, etc. but nothing will work.

Comment: I see you're trying to launch 16w40a, a snapshot.  Snapshots are often unstable and buggy.  As a test, are you able to launch 1.10.2?

Answer (score 0):

The error: "**OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.**" makes me think that this might deal with your graphics card drivers.

Have you tried updating your graphics card drivers? If not that should be the first thing you should try.

If it still doesn't work after that you might consider updating Java as well.